# How can I set the click event to disabled when draggable a button?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, draggable

I have created a movable.directive.ts with which you can move objects in the front-end. This directive also works so far. Unfortunately, I have the problem that my click event always opens when I move the button. Is there a way to deactivate the click at the draggable start and reactivate it at the draggable end? My Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/draggable-system-azomjp?file=app%2Fapp.component.html

My Code:

```
// movable.directive.ts
 @Input('appMovable') set movable(movable: boolean) {
    this.enabled = movable;
  }

  @HostListener('dragStart', ['$event']) onDragStart(event: PointerEvent): void {
    this.moving = true;
    this.startPosition = {
      x: event.clientX - this.position.x,
      y: event.clientY - this.position.y
    };
  }

  @HostListener('dragMove', ['$event']) onDragMove(event: PointerEvent): void {
    this.position = {
      x: event.clientX - this.startPosition.x,
      y: event.clientY - this.startPosition.y,
    };
  }

  @HostListener('dragEnd') onDragEnd(): void {
    this.moving = false;

    if (this.reset) {
      this.position = {
        x: 0,
        y: 0,
      };
    }
  }
```

```
// HTML
<button (click)="openAlert()" [appMovable]="true">
  My Button
</button>
```

```
// TS
openAlert() {
    alert("Hello World!");
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be an ongoing discussion about this on Github, there is also an example using `fromEvent` via `rxjs` but I was not successful using it in your stackblitz.

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9587

---

As an alternative, this rough POC demonstrates one way you could accomplish this by doing the following.

DI `Renderer2` in `moveable.directive.ts`

```
constructor(public element: ElementRef, private sanitizer: DomSanitizer, private ren: Renderer2) {
    super();
  }
```

Then in your `dragMove` set `pointer-events: none`

```
@HostListener('dragMove', ['$event']) onDragMove(event: PointerEvent): void {
    this.ren.setStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'pointer-events', 'none');
    this.position = {
```

Then in your `dragEnd` remove it

```
 @HostListener('dragEnd') onDragEnd(): void {
    this.ren.removeStyle(this.element.nativeElement, 'pointer-events');
    this.moving = false;
```

**STACKBLITZ**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/draggable-system-etearc?file=app/movable/moveable.directive.ts